# currency number format styles in webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to display my fare details as below.

```
Faredetails
-------------------
Price            : 1000
VAT              :   20(+)
GST              :   15(+)
Discount         :  100(-)
                ---------------
Total            : 1065
```

html code:

```
<div  class="div-active faredet">
                <h3 style="text-align:center;border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;">Fare Details</h3>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Fare&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&#x20B9;1,000.00</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Discuount&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&#8377;10.00<span style="color:red;">&nbsp;(-)</span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;"></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Net Payable&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&#8377;900.00</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </div>
```

All these values will come dynamically. so can any one let me how to style these values. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Give us some code we cant just write your whole script

Comment: @TimGerhard : updated code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do with accounting.js library.

```
<script src="path/to/accounting.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // Library ready to use:
    accounting.formatMoney(5318008);
</script>
```

refer:http://openexchangerates.github.io/accounting.js

Comment: i have checked that but it will not support INR currecy format.